# Can´t access JBOSS

Tags: linux, jboss, ejb, fedora

I´m using Fedora 17 and installed JBOSS via yum.
I configured in the standalone.xml the bind addresses of public and management to 0.0.0.0

But I still can´t access via :8080, my browser says, that he can´t connect to this address.

Any ideas what is going wrong there?

greetings 
Nox

Comment: Wha version of JBoss? What errors shows up in your server log?

Comment: Look at the log for a line similar to:   "20:12:49,866 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/127.0.0.1:8080"     The last characters show the address from which JBoss is listening. What does it appear in your log?

Comment: Well when I look at my server.log I got the following:

23:49:15,784 INFO [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-8080

It doesn´t look like a valid URL...

Comment: In that case you seem to have configured properly the jboss bind address in the standalone.xml file. So maybe it's a network problem. Are you trying to connect from the same computer where you've the Jboss installed, or another one? What's the exact URL you're using?

Comment: No, that´s the point the server where I installed jboss has no gui. Therefore I like to administrate jboss-as over a remote computer.
Yes, I configured it in the standalone.xml.
I sent you a pn with the exact URL.

Comment: @ToniS.Magraner could you send me a mail to nico@socialnerds.org, the I could tell you the exact URL, because I can´t send you a PN and I don´t like it to make the URL public...

Comment: I don't really need to know the exact address :-), I just wondered if you were trying to access using localhost, or the IP or servername. So, test that: try to access from the same server with the command line tool wget, for example: wget http://yourserveraddress:8080. This command will download the JBoss intro web, so if it works probaly it's not really a JBoss problem, but a network one. From your client machine you could also try to check the connection to the server with telnet, for example: telnet yourserveraddress 8080. Let us know the results of those commands. :-)

Comment: Ok :)
Well, when I try `curl localhost:8080` I got the HTML-code of the Jboss-site. But when I try telnet from another system I got `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: In that case, if you've been able to download locally the page(but using the ip or server name - not localhost) it's not really a JBoss problem, but a network problem. You should set up the server iptables to allow remote connections to the port 8080, and make sure that there is visibility between the two machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think binding to 0.0.0.0 binds it to all IP addresses on the machine. I know when I did this in the past, to access JBoss I had to use the pc name in the url. For example if my PC had a name of PC12345, I would use `http://PC12345:8080/` and you should get the initial JBoss window.

Normally we bind ours to localhost, which then we use `http://localhost:8080/` to connect. Sometimes I bind to the PC number and then I can use the pc again like above. `http://PC12345:8080`.